# Stream providers and await in Flutter - wait till data is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-provider

I am using StreamProviders in my Project and currently facing a problem, that the current setup doesn't let me wait till stiff is loaded before i show certain screens.

So here in my Home() i define my providers:

```
return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<PetUser?>(
            create: (context) => DatabaseService(uid: user?.uid).currentUser,
            initialData: null,
            catchError: (_, __) {},
          ),
          StreamProvider<Pet?>(
            create: (context) => DatabaseService(uid: user?.uid).petData,
            initialData: null,
            catchError: (_, __) {},
          ),
        ],
        child: Scaffold( ... ));
```

in my `database.dart` i've got:

```
Stream<PetUser> get currentUser {
    return ownersCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_currentUserFromSnapshot);
  }

  Stream<Pet> get petData {
    var map = petsCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_petDataFromSnapshot);
    print(map);
    return map;

  PetUser _currentUserFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    return PetUser(uid!, data['name']);
  }

  Pet _petDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    return Pet(uid!, data['petName'], null, null);
  }
```

So what i want i the further screens to how `Pet` and `PetUser` data, nut only after I know the loading from DB is complete.

How do I change such setup for it to be possible.

For now in my Profile Screen i call:

```
final user = Provider.of<PetUser?>(context);
```

and if i print its value it is first null, and after a while filled with data.

I am super new to the topic, so I also would accept tipps on how to completely change my approach.

Comment: the thing is: 
to get the corresponding pet data I need user's uid, which I can only get  from context (cause using Provider.of), so i can't do it form the init function...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snapshot.connectionState` to check the state of the data.

It is an enum so you can add a `snapshot.connectionState = ConnectionState.waiting` boolean test somewhere.